# Floating a div with image results in extra space

Tags: html, css, image, css-float

I have a div which floats left. Inside the div, I have an image. Following the diff is a paragraph.

I expect the paragraph to wrap around the image but I am seeing plenty of white space.

```css
.class-0-568 {
  float: left;
}

.class-0-569 {
  padding-right: 2%;
  width: 33%;
}

.class-0-570 {
  line-height: 1.2em;
  margin-top: 0.2816004em;
}
```

```html
<div class="class-0-568" id="id-0-553">
  <img alt="" class="class-0-569" id="id-0-554" src="https://i.postimg.cc/BZYZRfKP/image-0-4.jpg">
</div>
<p class="class-0-570" id="id-0-555">These offer a description of who you are</p>
```

Here is the output of above

[Output](https://i.postimg.cc/3r2rJfWn/Screenshot-2022-03-29-at-4-39-53-PM.png)

If I set the float property to img, then it is working as expected.

[Correct Output](https://i.postimg.cc/JhKJg4CH/Screenshot-2022-03-29-at-4-42-32-PM.png)

I dont understand why. Can someone please help me?

PS: JSFiddle link if anyone wants to play:

https://jsfiddle.net/chid1989/say7pzqe/#&togetherjs=z8iIlaQmNz

**EDIT**

I tried inspecting the elements through chrome. Apparently, the div is occupying the extra space. But I dont know why.

[Inspection](https://i.postimg.cc/d3m9Hprt/Screenshot-2022-03-29-at-6-03-16-PM.png)

Comment: when you add float to the image and not clearing the float the image remain floating, you can read more about clear https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your images width (caused by its class `.class-0-569`) is 33%. But that's of its *container*  / parent element, i.e. the floated `.class-0-568` element.

Apply the 33% width to the image's  **parent** (`.class-0-568`) and 100% width to the image itself:

```css
.class-0-568 {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
}

.class-0-569 {
  padding-right: 2%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.class-0-570 {
  line-height: 1.2em;
  margin-top: 0.2816004em;
}
```

```html
<div class="class-0-568" id="id-0-553">
  <img alt="" class="class-0-569" id="id-0-554" src="https://i.postimg.cc/BZYZRfKP/image-0-4.jpg">
</div>
<p class="class-0-570" id="id-0-555">These offer a description of who you are</p>
```

Addition after comments: The - actually much simpler - alternative is to float the image itself without using a wrapper div:

```css
#id-0-554 {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
  margin-right: 2%;
}


.class-0-570 {
  line-height: 1.2em;
  margin-top: 0.2816004em;
}
```

```html
 <img alt="" class="class-0-569" id="id-0-554" src="https://i.postimg.cc/BZYZRfKP/image-0-4.jpg">
<p class="class-0-570" id="id-0-555">These offer a description of who you are</p>
```

Comment: Thanks. Why do we need to specifically apply 100% width to the image? Actually, if i remove the `width: 100%` for img, it does not work.

Comment: To make it the width of its parent. The default would be "auto", which is the original size of the image. What's the problem about adding that?

Answer (score 1):

`<div>` and `<p>` are both block level elements. The correct way to float images in text is to place the `<img>` directly inside the `<p>`:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.class-0-569 {
  padding-right: 2%;
  width: 33%;
  float: left;
}

.class-0-570 {
  line-height: 1.2em;
  margin-top: 0.2816004em;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <p class="class-0-570" id="id-0-555">
    <img alt="" class="class-0-569" id="id-0-554" src="https://i.postimg.cc/BZYZRfKP/image-0-4.jpg">These offer a description of who you are
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tzgp14a3/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If both are block level elements, why is p behaving differently from div?

Comment: If you are referring to the space between the `img` and `p`, it's because you are setting the width of the `img` - which translates to the width of the parent - the `div`